# Read and Write to a File, An Arraylist which contains objects with an ArrayList

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have an ArrayList W1 containing Ward type objects and each Ward object have a Ward Name,Max Capacity,Current Capacity and an ArrayList P1 containing Patient type objects. Each Patient type object have a Name,Age,Address,gender..etc

i want to write the ArrayList W1 to file using bufferedwriter and read that file using bufferedreader.

i do know how to read from an ArrayList and write to a file. but in this case it confusing me because i am trying to read from an ArrayList which contains objects with ArrayList.

Please tell me how to do this.

Thanks

is there any other ways rather than this,

```
public static void addWardToFile(Ward ward)
{
     try
    {            
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("wardDetails.txt",true));

        Iterator itr = ward.wardPatients.iterator();

        String patient="";

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
         patient += itr.next().toString() + ":"; //patient object have a overridden toString method
        }
        out.write(ward.name +","+patients);
        out.newLine();
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: What should be the format of such file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class test1 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String filepath = "test.txt";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("5");
    list.add("6");

    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        sb.append(it.next());
        sb.append(",");
    }

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath));
    bw.write(sb.toString());
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
```

}

Comment: your example is perfect for an ArrayList with a simple elements(String,int,..etc).but in my case,my ArrayList W1 holds ward type objects,and a ward type object have a separate ArrayList to store ward patients. so i am asking how to store that ArrayList? should I store the W1 and store the ward patient ArrayList separate?

Comment: you can use like this: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hp = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

Comment: or : List<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested for loop.  Below is pseudocode:

```
for (w in W1){
    write w...
    for (p in w.P1){
        write p...
    }
}
```